# About the validity of arguments

Tags: logic

Studying the book *forall x: Calgary*, by  P. D. Magnus, I found this definition:

> An argument is valid if and only if the conclusion is a consequence of the premises.

In the glossary, it says:

> A property of arguments where it is impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion false.

- What would be the symbolic representation of both statements?
- How can I spot that premises and conclusion are connected, i.e. the conclusion follows from the premises? Are there a specific set of accepted form regarded as valid?

Comment: Is this book, perchance, the one by P. D. Magnus? Please [edit] the question to include that detail.

Comment: See page 84....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the symbolic representation of both statements?

Those definitions of the *validity of a semantic argument* are equivalent.

A conclusion is a logical consequence of the argument's premises **exactly when** it is impossible for that conclusion to be false *in any interpretation where* all of those premises are true.

Let $\Gamma$ be a *set* of statements and $\varphi$ a single statement. Then we indicate that an argument with premises of $\Gamma$ and conclusion of $\varphi$ is semantically valid by writing:

$$\Gamma\vDash\varphi$$

> How can I spot that premises and conclusion are connected, i.e. the conclusion follows from the premises? Are there a specific set of accepted form regarded as valid?

You should have some language and theory, or semantics, by which you can interpret and evaluate the truth of statements.

Take $p$ and $q$ as literals in the language, which represent propositions with values of true or false, and $\to$ as a logical connective in the language, such that the statement $p\to q$ is evaluated as false only when $p$ is true but $q$ false.   The argument that concludes $q$ under premises of $p$ and $p\to q$ , is semantically valid. The reason being, that it is impossible to value $q$ as false when valuing $p$ and $p\to q$ as true.

$$p, p\to q\vDash q$$